# Reading XML in a Stored Procedure

Tags: xml, stored-procedures, xlsx

I want to read an XLSX file into XML and the pass this XML to a stored procedure and read this xml inside the SP and insert records from the XML to a table.
here is my C# code

```
 FileStream stream = File.Open(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
   IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);

   DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

   excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;

   string xmlDS = result.GetXml();
```

I will pass xmlDS  as string to the SP. Now I need a SP to read this file and insert data into a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use OPENXML that provides a rowset view over an XML document

```
DECLARE @idoc int
DECLARE @doc varchar(1000)
SET @doc ='
<ROOT>
<Customer CustomerID="VINET" ContactName="Paul Henriot">
   <Order CustomerID="VINET" EmployeeID="5" OrderDate="1996-07-04T00:00:00">
      <OrderDetail OrderID="10248" ProductID="11" Quantity="12"/>
      <OrderDetail OrderID="10248" ProductID="42" Quantity="10"/>
   </Order>
</Customer>
<Customer CustomerID="LILAS" ContactName="Carlos Gonzlez">
   <Order CustomerID="LILAS" EmployeeID="3" OrderDate="1996-08-16T00:00:00">
      <OrderDetail OrderID="10283" ProductID="72" Quantity="3"/>
   </Order>
</Customer>
</ROOT>'
--Create an internal representation of the XML document.
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc
-- Execute a SELECT statement that uses the OPENXML rowset provider.
SELECT    *
FROM       OPENXML (@idoc, '/ROOT/Customer',1)
            WITH (CustomerID  varchar(10),
                  ContactName varchar(20))
```

for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx

then you can use the SELECT to insert your data as showed [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-select-to-insert-records)

Comment: my xml is like <NewDataSet>
  <Sheet1>
    <Column1>Name</Column1>
    <Column2>Fname</Column2>
  </Sheet1></NewDataSet>

Comment: BEGIN TRY       
   INSERT INTO testing ( [Name] ,[Fname] )
   SELECT * 
   FROM OPENXML (@idoc, 'NewDataSet/Sheet1', 1)
   WITH ([Column1] [varchar](25),
         [Column2] [varchar](25))
                                                                           
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        
    END CATCH,this only inserts NULL in table